# How to implement a flutter drawer menu-submenu feature where menu-submenu rendering needs to be done with a standard data format such as JSON?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have to implement a flutter drawer menu-submenu feature where menu-submenu rendering needs to be done with a standard data format such as JSON and should be dynamic, as different roles will have different menus.

I have implemented multilevel drawer with the help of multilevel_drawer: ^2.0.0 dependency. But in actual project development scenario I have to implement same thing but with JSON data. How to proceed with that? Is there any plug-in for that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have tried in this way, Link: https://pub.dev/packages/multilevel_drawer but it does not use JSON data. I could not find the approach using JSON. Please help me out.